# Using ObjectDataProvider

Tags: wpf, xaml, objectdataprovider, app.xaml

I cannot believe that nobody has gotten across this or perhaps I'm just missing something.

I've got a custom DataSourceController which handles retrieving data and providing it to the rest of the application controls. Naturally, it uses sql connection which I also initialize.

My App code:

```
private ISQLConnection conn;
public ISQLConnection SqlConnection { get { return conn; } }

private DataSourceController dataSource;
public DataSourceController DataSource { get { return dataSource; } }

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize connections
    conn = new OracleSQLConnection("connectionStringHere");

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize controllers
    //dataSource = new DataSourceController(conn);

    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

Now I want to create ObjectDataProvider in XAML and then use it for binding data in controls:

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type data:DataSourceController}" x:Key="DataSource" MethodName="GetVenues" />
```

The problem is that the DataSourceController does not have a parameterless constructor and requires an OracleSQLConnection object to be passed in (which is a public property in my App code-behind).

Is this at all possible? Or I have to resort to using in-code DataContext property for each control I want to data-bind?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the `DataSourceController` as a resource (you'll have to do this from code-behind if you don't have a parameterless constructor) and use the [ObjectDataProvider.ObjectInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.objectinstance.aspx) property to get the `DataSourceController` instance, then you can execute methods on it:

```
private ISQLConnection conn;
public ISQLConnection SqlConnection { get { return conn; } }

private DataSourceController dataSource;
public DataSourceController DataSource { get { return dataSource; } }

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   // Initialize connections
   conn = new OracleSQLConnection("connectionStringHere");

   //-------------------------------------------------------
   // Initialize controllers
   dataSource = new DataSourceController(conn);
   this.Resources.Add("myDataController", dataSource);
   base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

`ObjectInstance` can take a resource:

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource myDataController}" x:Key="DataSource" MethodName="GetVenues" />
```

There might be issues if your `ObjectDataProvider` is in App.xaml where it could be parsed before the `DataSourceController` resource is added, in which case you'd get an error because the "`myDataController`" resources wouldn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks Robert! I tried this and it worked! Although I then had some (unrelated) problems further down the road and had to opt out for in-code init and then setting the object as DataContext of my window.