# With a WPF MainWindow with four TabItems with the same content (one View, ViewModel), how to tell the View which TabItem it belongs?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, tabitem

My next step in exploring/learning WPF/MVVM brought me to a MainWindow with a TabControl and four TabItems. Each tab has the same content, a set of four CheckBoxes defined in one View and consequently in one ViewModel.
As I can see from various Debug.WriteLine statements in various constructors the one View is instantiated four times as well the ViewModel four times.

[Four TabItems, same content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moQRr.png)

So far so good, but the data of each tab should be stored in a backend (yet to be determined) so I need to inform the View instances and consequently the ViewModel instances to which TagItem they belong. So that the checked CheckBoxes of each TabItem can be stored separately.

I did try to use the ObjectDataProvider  [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638911/using-objectdataprovider)  to pass an argument to the OneView constructor but could not get it working. Any suggestions?

`<Window x:Class="FourTabsOneView.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vws="clr-namespace:FourTabsOneView.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
    <TabControl x:Name="tControl">
        <TabItem x:Name="One" Header="TabOne" Width="80">
            <vws:OneView/>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem x:Name="Two" Header="TabTwo" Width="80">
            <vws:OneView/>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem x:Name="Three" Header="TabThree" Width="80">
            <vws:OneView/>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem x:Name="Four" Header="TabFour" Width="80">
            <vws:OneView/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>

<UserControl x:Class="FourTabsOneView.Views.OneView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:FourTabsOneView.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vms:OneViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <CheckBox x:Name="cb01" IsThreeState="False" Height="30" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding CB01}"
                          Content="CheckBox A" />
        <CheckBox x:Name="cb02" IsThreeState="False" Height="30"
                          IsChecked="{Binding CB02}"
                          Content="CheckBox B" />
        <CheckBox x:Name="cb03" IsThreeState="False" Height="30"
                          IsChecked="{Binding CB03}"
                          Content="CheckBox C" />
        <CheckBox x:Name="cb04" IsThreeState="False" Height="30"
                          IsChecked="{Binding CB04}"
                          Content="CheckBox D" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this is by creating an observable collection in your view model that holds each of the children's view models you want, and then binding the collection to the `TabControl`'s `ItemsSource` property. That will populate the tab control with one tab for each of your elements in the collection.

The rest of the story is simple, just templates. You have your `ContentTemplate` property which defines how the children should look (your user control) and your `ItemTemplate` which defines how the header should look (a text block bound to a `Name` property in your childrens' VM).

Also don't try to manually change your user control's data context, it's already handled by the framework to be correct.

Comment: Also to be clear, you don't need your user control, you can just define the content template inline.

Comment: Thank you Blindy. I will have a look at this items...

Comment: @AadSlingerland See an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651542/1136211.

Comment: @Clemens TX! Very good example...